# how to use the isset() command in code below for $_SESSION

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

I have a basic question asking how to use the isset(); command and how it should be written in the example below. I am trying to insert values into  query, then retrive the last ImageId inserted and insert that into another table

```
    session_start();


         $imagesql = "INSERT INTO Image (ImageFile) 
        VALUES (?)";

                if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($imagesql)) {
          // Handle errors with prepare operation here
        }

        //Dont pass data directly to bind_param store it in a variable
    $insert->bind_param("s",$img);

    //Assign the variable
    $img = 'ImageFiles/'.$_FILES['fileImage']['name'];

     $insert->execute();

            if ($insert->errno) {
              // Handle query error here
            }

            $insert->close();

            $lastImageID = $mysqli->insert_id;     

        $_SESSION['lastImageID'] = $lastImageID; 

$imagequestionsql = "INSERT INTO Image_Question (ImageId, SessionId, QuestionId)  
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)"; 

     if (!$insertimagequestion = $mysqli->prepare($imagequestionsql)) { 
      // Handle errors with prepare operation here 
       echo "Prepare statement err imagequestion"; 
    } 

$qnum = (int)$_POST['numimage'];

$insertimagequestion->bind_param("iii",$lastImageID, $sessionid, $qnum); 

    $insertimagequestion->execute(); 

                if ($insertimagequestion->errno) { 
          // Handle query error here 
        } 

        $insertimagequestion->close();
```

Comment: @Geoff_Montee code and question updated to give more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what your asking for, but guessing wildly:

```
session_start();

...... //PDO code and commands

   $lastImageID = $mysqli->insert_id; 
   $_SESSION['lastImageID'] = $lastImageID; 

   if (isset($_SESSION['lastImageID'])) {
      // do this
   } else {
      // do that
   }
```

Comment: code and question updated to give more info so u dont have to guess

Comment: So where are you trying to isset()? What variable?

Comment: Well I an not sure if I will get undefined variable for the $_SESSION variable, meaning do I need to call an isset first at top of page before doing `   $_SESSION['lastImageID'] = $lastImageID; `?

Comment: NO! The variable doesn't exist until you set it. You will always get a `$mysqli->insert_id` back from the DB (unless there is a major failure - in which case your code will fail prior to that point and which you should account for; failing gracefully).

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for your comments on this :) I have learned something new

Comment: You're welcome! If an answer and comments help you - accept them as an answer by clicking the tick! :)

Answer (score 0):

You only need to call `isset` if you are reading a variable that may not be defined.

In this situation, you are writing to `$_SESSION['lastImageID']`, so you don't need to check.

An example of where `isset` would be needed:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['lastImageID']))
{
    $lastImageID = $_SESSION['lastImageID'];
}

else
{
    $lastImageID = get_this_from_db_or_something();
}
```